# Replace second occurrence of a string in Angular

Tags: angular

```
str = "oreo contains oreo";
```

*change 2nd oreo to chocklate*

```
result = "oreo contains choklate";
```

replace nth occurance of string in angular 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp Constructor:

```
const replace_nth = function (s, f, r, n) {
    // From the given string s, replace f with r of nth occurrence
    return s.replace(RegExp("^(?:.*?" + f + "){" + n + "}"), x => x.replace(RegExp(f + "$"), r));
};
```